# Multiple jobs in Jenkins are triggering after code delivery in RTC work stream

Tags: jenkins, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I have a work stream in which, I have multiple projects (Components) and for each project i have created a separate jobs in Jenkins.

I am looking the solution for my issue, First i will explain the scenario of my work stream.

### **Explanation of RTC work stream**

I have a work stream, in which i have created two separate projects (Project "A" and Project "B")

Tree diagram of work stream given below:

[image]

### **Explanation of Jenkins**

I have created two separate jobs in Jenkins like (Job for project "A" and Job for project "B"). I am using Ant 1.9.14 for build.

### **explanation of Issue**

All the setup of Jenkins jobs and RTC are done, Jobs are triggering and creating build files successfully.

Main issue is that, Currently i am working on project "A" and doing check-in and delivering code properly in my main work stream for project "A", but as soon as I deliver code in my work stream for project "A" Jenkins build starts for both projects.

So, Is there any way to start a specific project build in Jenkins?